# Multiple Area Charts with D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am integrating a few d3js libraries inmy project and in this step I want to draw a multiple area graph showing values(between 0 and 100%) of 5(x,y,z,r,e) points in function of the time just like this:http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MultipleAreaChartsD3/  ...In my case input is an array

```
var data =  
 [{"Year":"2011","x":"63.4","y":"62.7","z":"12.2","t":"44.2","e":"22.2"},              
 {"Year":"2012","x":"75.4","y":"32.7","z":"78.2","t":"82.2","e":"92.2"},  
 {"Year":"2013","x":"773.4","y":"20.7","z":"92.2","t":"75.4","e":"52.2"}];
```

as defined in my code:http://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/cfk8Y/ I just edited some lines of the original code but there is problems when showing y,z,r,e values also css issues ..question is how to read data proprely from array form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you seem to have read in the data correctly from what I can see.  I forked your fiddle to [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LHC3R/) and all I did was change some of the css to reflect the variable names i.e. I changed the countries to x,y,z,t,e as in:

```
g.x path.chart{
      fill: rgb(127,201,127);
    }
```

The only other change I made was to the maxDataPoint which was including the Year column in the calculation of max, so I simply excluded it in the if statement as in:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (var prop in d) {
    console.log(d[prop])
    if (d.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      d[prop] = parseFloat(d[prop]);
    if (d[prop] > maxDataPoint && prop !== "Year") {
      console.log(prop)
      maxDataPoint = d[prop];
    }
  }
};
```

I think that's what you were after anyway.

```
EDIT
```

And to add colours you need to add the fill attribute to the path generation as in (last line):

```
  this.chartContainer.append("path")
                      .data([this.chartData])
                      .attr("class", "chart")
                      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-" + this.id + ")")
                      .attr("d", this.area)
                      .attr("fill", function (d,i) { return colours(options.id); });
```

The fill or colour is defined through the custom function using the id from options and an ordinal scale for the colours (one of the built in colour scales from d3 based on Color Brewer) defined as:

```
var colours = d3.scale.category20();
```

You need to declare this as a global so you can access it in Chart function.  You can read more on ordinal scales [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales).

I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHC3R/1/) with this.

Comment: Thx :) yes it works because I fixe it, it was only a little mistake :)

Comment: but I want to Know how to have a ulticolor graph without writting x,y,z...in the css code, because the input array will change evry time so I dont want to put values in the css that change dynamicly, how it can be done? can we give evry chart an ID and then refer to the id from the css?